# How to return a method from a String?

Tags: java, string, reflection

```
public AbstractImagePrototype getIcon(ModelData model) {
    if (model.get("icon") != null) {
        return Resources.ICONS.lock();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

in this line of code:

```
return Resources.ICONS.lock();
```

I need to change `lock()` for a String, e.g.

```
String text = "lock()";
return Resources.ICONS.text;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could add some more details to what you're trying to do. This way maybe we can suggest some friendlier approach.

Comment: You just want the method that you call to be specified by a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
Resources.ICONS.getClass().getMethod("lock").invoke(Resources.ICONS);
```

at leas if ICONS is an object. If it is a class it could be

```
Resources.ICONS.class.getMethod("lock").invoke(null);
```

(untested).

I hope you know what you are doing, because that could have a number of effects you don't want.

Comment: I wonder how many headaches the people who had to write the code to add reflection to Java had while they were writing it, considering how convoluted they had to make it to work with Java as it is...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a single method that accepts a string as input. It will then compare the string and then call on the function.

```
if (command.equals("lock()"))
    lock();
// etc.
```

Comment: or whatever the syntax would be. I'm confusing all the languages lol. So whatever the equal operator for string comparison is for java.

Comment: @Spaeth Actually you might get lucky due to the way String is implemented in java (flyweight & co.), that is if you don't have an invocation such as `new String("lock()")`. However you are right, and since String is an object you'd want to use `.equals` to verify equality. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to obtain some kind of an object that you'll be needing to invoke later, you should take a look at the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)